# 'wss://' NodeJS Connection

Tags: node.js

I am using [BinaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md) to stream to a server. But at this moment I put my page in HTTPS (OPENSSL). This is why all create the connection in the client:

```
var client = new BinaryClient('wss://my_IP:9050');
```

If I use `ws` the browser will give error because this is not a protected connection and the page use https. But I am having an error anyway:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_IP:9050/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

And the server Code is:

```
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
binaryServer = BinaryServer({ port: 9050});
```

Should the `binaryserver` using some certificate? I cant understand the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here:

```
binaryServer = BinaryServer({ 
  //port: 9000 //BinaryServer will share the same port of httpsServer 
  server: serverHTTPS, //Server previously defined


});
```

Based on this [link](http://www.chovy.com/web-development/self-signed-certs-with-secure-websockets-in-node-js/)